# Achieving a specific design goal with HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with regards to achieving a specific design goal, and I hope you can help me out here.

I made a picture in PS that I hope explains to you what I want:

[image: Example 1]

Every part of this picture should be in an individual tag (for example div), and be placed like this. 
The logo should be placed on top of the big picture, with just a little bit of space between the edges. The name is placed on level with the bottom of the picture OR in the middle (whatever looks best).

The headline (new 911) is placed along with the top of the big picture, the description is in the middle (always middle, length of text will vary) and the footer (info info) is aligned with the bottom of the picture.

Is this something anyone could help me with?

---

I have some code, but it doesn't work exactly as planned. Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="content">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="poster">
      <div class="poster_img">
        <img src="https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-cC6WK7FOx_g/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/QQ41pWU9UUQ/s100-c-k/photo.jpg" height="50" />
      </div>
      <div class="poster_name">Porsche</div>
    </div>
    <div class="img">
      <img src="http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/k7dEsMCFfFw/mqdefault.jpg" width="220" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="header">The new Porsche 911 Turbo. Breaking new ground.</div>
    <div class="main">With the new Porsche 911 Turbo, we have once again questioned everything and started from scratch. We pushed the boundaries...</div>
    <div class="footer">
    <div class="info1">info</div>
    <div class="info2">info</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's my CSS:

```
.content {
  position: relative;
  clear: all;
  margin: 5px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}   

.left {
  display: table-cell;
}

.poster {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: -50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.poster_img {
  display: table-cell;
  position: absolute;   
}

.poster_name {
  display: table-cell;
  padding-left: 52px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.img {}

.right {
  display: table-cell;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.header {}

.main {}

.footer {}

.info1 {
  display: table-cell;
}

.info2 {
  display:table-cell;
  padding-left: 25px;
}
```

Hope you can help me out here! :)

- Aleksander.

Comment: You should be able to do everything with `position:absolute`. Just make sure the container has position of `relative` for it to work. This question is asking for too much help, overall.

Comment: Give me a few minutes and let me see if I can make this look good.

Comment: @itcouldevenbeaboat No, it doesn't. It only mustn't have position: static; absolute will work just fine.

Comment: No need for all `absolute`. Just the logo, text on top of image and image itself need `position:absolute`

Comment: The image, too? seems like it would be easier to include the image in the flow of the pattern with display block and a max width and max height to allow the text to fall in beside it.

Comment: put the image as background image

Answer (score 1):

Positioning elements with CSS is not as complicated as it seems (if your design concept is good).

I like using grids to cleanly position elements. However most of the time `position: absolute;` with a `position: relative;` on the parent element will suffice.

Read on about this here: [Absolute Positioning Inside Relative Positioning](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/)

Also try to find a site that has a similar design and explore the source. It looks like porsche would be a good place to start. There are also lots of "[Design Inspiration](http://www.google.com/search?q=css%20design%20inspiration)" sites were you might find what you're looking for.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Rather then going into the depths of positioning, you may want to consider a simple float in combination with clear. usually works well enough - given the right stack order.